# GKMatchmakerViewController failed

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

In my app, I can see data for `Leaderboards` and `Achievements` that I have created using iTunesConnect.  I can use `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController` with no problem.  But if I use `GKMatchmakerViewController`, immediately after selected a friend to invite, the `GKMatchmakerViewController` comes back with a "failed" indication (see image).

That was not all.  If I use another bundle id (one that already on AppStore) just to test, then GKMatchmakerViewController will work on this app.

I have also tried to create new profile/bundle id, app id, etc. But the problem persists.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Neither `connectionWithPlayerFailed` nor `didFailWithError` method was called when it failed.

Edit 2:

This messages showed up in device logs:

> Unable to bootstrap_look_up port with name
>   com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterMatchmakerExtension.gsEvents: unknown
>   error code (1102) Failed to set
>   com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterMatchmakerExtension as keyboard focus

Edit 3:  The "Play Now" (Auto-match) works fine.

[image]

Edit: code used

```
- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers
                 viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                       delegate:(id<GameKitHelperDelegate>)delegate {

    if (!_enableGameCenter) return;
    MyNSLogSys;
    _matchStarted = NO;
    self.match = nil;
    _delegate = delegate;
//    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
    request.minPlayers = minPlayers;
    request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;

    GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc =
    [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

    [viewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];

}

// The user has cancelled matchmaking
- (void)matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController {
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

// Matchmaking has failed with an error
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"Error finding match: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}

// A peer-to-peer match has been found, the game should start
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)match {
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.match = match;
    match.delegate = self;
    if (!_matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Ready to start match!");
    }
}
```

Comment: please show the code where you launch the matchmaker and check the error

Comment: @Thunk: adding code.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before.  The way around it is to become friends through the game center.  After that, the invites should work.

Furthermore, in iOS9, there is no longer a sandbox.  So, if you are trying to connect using a debug version of your app, the notification will open game center and app store rather than going directly to your app.  You can get around this simply by running in release mode instead of debug mode.

Comment: The two players involved are already friends. Since this is for inviting, so there is no notification involved yet.  I have also tried to run the app as release mode.  Both invitation from GC app or directly my app failed as described in my post.

Comment: I had this problem and was only able to get around it by using a different player.  It seemed as though there was something flagged with these two players making it always fail through game center.  You can also test by inviting someone you recently played. First play through 'play now' and then go to invite and you should see the user under recent tab.

Comment: It seemed to be working fine now.  They probably have fixed it problem recently.