# Game Center not working with different devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, multiplayer

I was following this tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/game-center-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-part-12#comments), to create multiplayer game using Game Center. I have iPhone 5 and 6s+ both running ios 9.1 and I can't get those two working. Although, If I use same devices (iPhone 5 in simulator and iPhone 5, or iPhone 6s+ in simulator and iPhone 6s+) everything works like it should (using auto-match).

What could be the problem?

PS. Inviting a friend always gives "failed".

EDIT:

I also get `plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterMatchmakerExtension invalidated.`

Comment: I also have troubles getting inviting friends to work. However, in a test app I can connect the iPhone5 with an iPhone4s in simulator. I can also auto match between an iPad Air 2 and the iPhone5 (all iOS9.1).

Comment: So strange, I just tried iphone5 with iPhone 4s simulator and it works although I still get 'plugin invalidated'. Seems like it has something to do with 6s/6s+ devices ...

Comment: Same problem here with inviting friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902327/gkmatchmakerviewcontroller-failed

Comment: @EmilyJ Could you please try if auto-match works for you using iPhone5/4s and iPhone6s/6s+?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have those devices.